# Local buffer for downloads directly to network drive

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, download

Apologies if this is a very trivial question. I'm intending to use a Windows platform to download several large files from the internet directly to another networked location (web-based network drive, mapped via WebDAV). The network destination has plenty of storage capacity, but the local machine doing the download has a very small SSD (40GB). Each individual file to be downloaded has a size greater than the local HDD capacity of the download machine (>50GB).

Is such a transfer technically feasible? Will windows write directly to the network destination during the download, or does it require any form of local storage buffer equal to or greater than the capacity of each download file in order to succeed?

Comment: That depends on what program you use to initiate the download and how it handles its temporary data/downloads.

Comment: I see. Can anyone provide any recommendations on a browser that supports customisable temporary download settings that would be suitable for this situation? Unfortunately the downloads require browser authentication, so just handing them off to a 3rd party download manager results in authentication errors.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox will save downloads directly to the destination folder without touching your ssd. Edge however will create a temporary file on your ssd first.